# node-sass Issue on my angular project npm install (Mac OS)

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, sass

I try to install node_modules for my angular project an I get issue for node-sass
I use mac os, node js version -> v16.13.2, node-sass version in project ->^4.14.1
In this [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MQet.png) and [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OypEs.png) is package.json
The error that I get is :

```
npm ERR! 1 warning and 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (../node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" ".../node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd .../node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     .../.npm/_logs/2022-01-25T10_04_49_137Z-debug-0.log
```

I tied this commands npm install -g node-sass, npm uninstall -g node-sass
The same I tried to install latest version of node-sass

Answer (score 1):

Just remove node-sass from your package.json ... that solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem. Simply to downgrade node version and it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run `npm upgrade` to have npm check for outdated version of your dependencies.

Because for node 16 you need node-sass in version 6.0+

Comment: If I update node-sass to 6.0+ version I get this error "Error: Node Sass version 6.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
"

Comment: It might help to first uninstall node-sass, then reinstall. So first `npm uninstall node-sass` and then `npm i node-sass`

Comment: I did it several times and nothing :(

Comment: Where do you run your web project? Since you wrote its on macOS, does that imply that you don't use a virtual host like Docker, Homestead/Valet or MAMP?

Answer (score 0):

## First solution

Make sure your `node.js` version is not superior to the [recommended](https://nodejs.org/en/) one. If not, downgrade it, and for that, you could use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package from `npm`:

```bash
npm install -g n
n stable
# If one of the commands does not pass, you may need to use sudo
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Then you would wanna use [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) package instead of [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), as it's deprecated. And for that, run those commands:

```bash
npm uninstall node-sass --save
npm install sass --save
```

## Second solution

If you need or want `node-sass` for some reason, you should downgrade your `nodejs` version to like `v14`. For that you can use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package from `npm`:

```bash
npm install -g n
n 14
# If one of the commands does not pass, you may need to use sudo
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 14
```